# Oracle err handling

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a proceudre and trying to do some logging of sql insert query success status.
I have no clue how to write the if ERR insert to a error log table.

```
insert into TableA (select * from TableB);
commit;

**if (show ERR <> NULL)
 insert into TableErr**
```

can anyone guy me how shall I do it? Try search but don't know what key to look for

Comment: You need to enclose it in block. See if this helps [link]http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Exception Handling".  Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-exception-handling.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As well as the classic approach to handling errors in PL/SQL, if you're loading bulk data using SQL then consider using an error handling table.

From the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/tables004.htm#InsertDMLErrorLogging

> When you load a table using an INSERT statement with subquery, if an
>   error occurs, the statement is terminated and rolled back in its
>   entirety. This can be wasteful of time and system resources. For such
>   INSERT statements, you can avoid this situation by using the DML error
>   logging feature.
>
> To use DML error logging, you add a statement clause that specifies
>   the name of an error logging table into which the database records
>   errors encountered during DML operations. When you add this error
>   logging clause to the INSERT statement, certain types of errors no
>   longer terminate and roll back the statement. Instead, each error is
>   logged and the statement continues. You then take corrective action on
>   the erroneous rows at a later time.